# Sobre (function(){ ... }()) e callThis()

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

O CoffeeScript compila seus arquivos dentro de um:

```
(function(){
  // código aqui
}()).callThis();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHrPp/

Algumas vezes encontramos na internet uma variação:

```
(function(){
  // código aqui
}());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pSK43/

---

Qual é a utilidade disso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A principal utilidade destas [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (função imediatamente auto-invocada) é criar uma clausura para variáveis. Assim todas as variáveis defenidas dentro dessa clausura não são exportadas para o espaço global, e portanto não o poluíndo.

Essa funcionalidade tem a ver com o funcionamento normal das funções e como elas criam/alteram o escopo do código. O que é diferente aqui é que ele é imediatamente invocada/corrida e não fica à espera de ser chamada.

A outra razão importante é que as variaveis criadas ficam dentro daquele escopo e são libretadas da memoria depois da função correr, passando o seu valor para fora caso necessário (ver exemplo 2 em baixo).

Alguns exemplos práticos desta aplicação:

**Exemplo 1:**

```
(function(global){
  // código aqui
})(this);
```

Neste exemplo passamos para dentro da função o `this` do espaço global. No caso de javascript do lado do cliente isto será `window` mas no caso de Node.JS isto será o `global`.

**Exemplo 2:**

```
// #2479 - IE8 Cannot set HTML of style element
var canChangeStyleHtml = (function(){
    var div = document.createElement('style'),
        flag = false;
    try {
        div.innerHTML = '#justTesing{margin: 0px;}';
        flag = !!div.innerHTML;
    } catch(e){}
    return flag;
})();
```

Este exemplo em cima fiz para a biblioteca do MooTools para saber se o browser em que o código é corrido consegue mudar o HTML de um elemento `<style>`. Desta maneira a função corre (auto-invocada) retorna `true` ou `false`. Assim eu tenho essa informação guardada e posso usar no resto do meu código, e não preciso de correr mais essa função.

**Exemplo 3:**

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        var numero = Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert(numero);
        });
    })();
}
```

Este exemplo mostra um ciclo `for` no qual cada iteração corre uma IIFE. Essa função cria um escopo próprio que é passado e guardado. Assim a cada vez que clica num botão ele vai ter na memória o valor que lhe corresponde, sem ser re-escrito. Exemplo online: http://jsfiddle.net/dR8KG/, e já agora o mesmo exemplo sem a IIFE: http://jsfiddle.net/dR8KG/1/ - todos os botões têm o mesmo valor.

Comment: Agora não percebi, primeiro dizes: "Assim todas as variáveis defenidas dentro dessa clausura não são exportadas para o espaço global, e portanto não o poluindo" depois no fim dizes "Assim a cada vez que clica num botão ele vai ter na memória o valor que lhe corresponde". Afinal em que ficamos? Não percebi mesmo.

Comment: @JorgeB. no caso do exemplo 3, as variáveis não estão disponíveis no espaço global. Elas ficam guardadas em memória e são chamadas dentro do event handler. Isto é muito util para evitar sobreescrever uma variável.

Comment: Ah entendi, tu tens aquelas variáveis em memória e não vão mudar nunca, porque estão diretamente apontadas do botão, certo?

Comment: @JorgeB. exato! dá uma olhada a à consola neste fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dR8KG/2/) e depois tira os comments para a IIFE estar ativa. No primeiro caso o valor de numero é global e foi sobreescrito até fazer log só do ultimo valor que teve. No segundo caso (depois de tirares os comments `//`) a variável numero não está declarada, mas existe na memoria para cada botão.

Comment: +1 Muito porreiro isso, percebi agora.