# Como chamar funções Javascript em outro Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu queria chamar uma function de um Javascript em outro arquivo Javascript.

Por exemplo, no arquivo *calcular.js*, eu tenho a function **somar(a,b)**. E eu precisava, chamar essa function no arquivo *calculadora.js* (por exemplo).

Eu queria saber se é possível essa comunicação entre dois ou mais arquivos js. E como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O seu primeiro Javascript deve criar a função no escopo global, através de `window.`:

```
var window.somar = function(a, b) {
  // código aqui
};
```

Assim ele se torna visível no outro arquivo desde que ele seja incluído primeiro:

```html
<script src="calcular.js"></script>
<script src="calculadora.js"></script>
```

Comment: Correto. Mas não precisa explicitamente escrever `window.somar`. `var somar = function(a,b)` ou `function somar(a, b)` também funcionam.

Comment: Não precisa informar window se você está no escopo global de um único documento

Comment: @Beterraba Sim, mas digamos que este é o jeito mais "seguro", pois se você declarar esta função dentro do escopo de outra, ela não se torna visível (se você estiver usando [esta abordagem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/7261), por exemplo).

Comment: Ae galera, valeu pela ajuda, isso me ajuda bastante. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

As funções que você carrega no escopo global poderão ser utilizadas em qualquer script que é carregado na sequência. Isto serve tanto para javascript inline quanto incluídos.

Você também poderá fazer com que o primeiro script execute uma função existente no segundo script, mas para isso deverá engatilhar a execução ao evento `onload`do documento como este exemplo (usando jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   somar(a,b); //somar() ainda será definido
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Valeu :)

Answer (score 0):

Só colocar:

```
window.parent.nomedafuncao();
```

Exemplo:

```
window.parent.sw(‘teste’);
```