# Botões com estilo em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, aplicação-web

Estou tentando fazer em uma página, que botões que sejam clicados alterem seu estilo e também passem a exibir uma div ao serem clicados. Só que eles devem ser mutuamente exclusivos, ou seja, quando eu clicar em um, somente a div atrelada ao botão deve ser exibida e somente o botão clicado deve ter seu estilo alterado. O código que tenho utilizado é o seguinte:

```
//Adiciona eventos a cada botão
//Classe CSS 'side-button' para estado padrão e 'clicked-button' quando clicado
function buttonEventDef(){

  var current;

  for(var i=0; i<btns.length; i++){

      current = i;
      btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

          this.classList.remove('side-button');
          this.classList.add('clicked-button');
        show[current].style.display = 'initial';

          for(var j=0; j<btns.length; j++){
              if(j!=current){
                  btns[j].classList.remove('clicked-button');
                  btns[j].classList.add('side-button');
                  show[j].style.display = 'none';
              }
          }

      });

  }

}
```

Mas quando eu aperto um botão ele a mentém o seu estilo , mesmo após eu apertar outro botão. As divs sguem o mesmo comportamnto quanto a visibilidade.

Por acaso há uma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para guardares esse `i`/`current` dentro do ciclo `for` tens de criar um novo escopo. Dessa maneira podes guardar por exemplo `var thisIndex = i;` e ter a certeza que esse valor se mantém na memória e não é re-escrito na proxima iteração do ciclo `for`.

Sugestão:

```
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        var thisIndex = i;
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.classList.remove('side-button');
            this.classList.add('clicked-button');
            show[thisIndex].style.display = 'initial';

            for (var j = 0; j < btns.length; j++) {
                if (j != thisIndex) {
                    btns[j].classList.remove('clicked-button');
                    btns[j].classList.add('side-button');
                    show[j].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        });
    })();
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxe1h0e2/

Comment: Isso funcionou, muito obrigado! Posso apenas saber por quê colocar a função dentro do primeiro for dentro dentro de parênteses, e também o porque de abrir e fechar depois destes?

Comment: @HianNeiva fico contente de ter ajudado. Dá uma olhada aqui sobre IIFEs: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129

Comment: Agora compreendo. É importante saber sobre as IIFEs já que as vezes JS pode confuso quanto o escopo de variáveis e funções. Novamente, muito obrigado!