# É possível chamar uma função anônima?

Tags: javascript, função-anônima

Gostaria de saber se é possível chamar uma função anônima fora do escopo dela.

Quando eu chamo a função, ocorre esse erro:

---

```
Uncaught TypeError: consomeCsr is not a function
```

---

Exemplo:

```js
  consomeCsr = (function () {
     alert('Funcção Anonima')
        })();

        consomeCsr();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possivel chamar uma função anónima se ela não for atribuída a uma variável.

No teu exemplo:

```
consomeCsr = (function () {
  return alert('Funcção Anonima')
})();

consomeCsr();
```

`consomeCsr` não é uma função. Essa [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129) é corrida imediatamente e a variável `consomeCsr` recebe o valor de `undefined`, que é o que o `alert` deixa/retorna.

Se quiseres ter uma função que corra esse alert então deves ter:

```
var consomeCsr = function () {
  alert('Funcção Anonima');
};
```

Porém se quiseres uma função que se auto-execute ([IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129)) mas que fique também numa variável para usar mais tarde, tens de lhe dar um nome para a poder retornar e reutilizar assim:

```
var consomeCsr = (function autoExecutavel() {
    alert('Funcção Anonima');
    return autoExecutavel;
})();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5q3L1xdr/1/