# Para que serve o "function" entre parênteses, no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Eu já notei que existem códigos mais ou menos assim:**

```
<script>
    (function (parametros){})
</script>
```

**Outro código semelhante:**

```
(function (val) {
    return val;
})(123);
```

Qual a utilidade disso?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/129