# Por que posso criar duas funções com a mesma assinatura em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou com duvidas sobre uma certa questão em Javascript, suponha o seguinte cenário abaixo:

```js
function teste() {
  console.log("teste1");
}

function teste() {
  console.log("teste2");
}

teste();
```

Nesse caso eu percebi que o meu método `teste()` foi meio que sobrescrito, não sei se é realmente isso que acontece, quando chamamos o mesmo só o *teste2* que é exibido. Agora as duvidas em relação a isso:

1. Esse é realmente o comportamento esperado quando declaramos 2
   métodos com o mesmo nome e parâmetros no js, ele irá sempre
   sobrescrever e vai prevalecer o último declarado?
2. Existe alguma explicação para esse comportamento, se sim qual é essa
   explicação?
3. Existe alguma forma de fazer que gere algum erro ou algo do tipo
   caso alguém cometa esse equivoco e declare 2 métodos com o mesmo
   nome e parâmetros?
4. Caso a 3 tenha alguma maneira de fazer, o que fazer caso as funções
   estejam em arquivos js diferentes?

Comment: Essa duvida deve ter surgido por você estar acostumado com programação tipada, na qual podem existir métodos "iguais" com parâmetros diferentes.

Comment: Link relacionado: [Possibilitando o overload de métodos em Javascript](http://blog.caelum.com.br/possibilitando-o-overload-de-metodos-em-javascript/)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic pode ser engano meu, `function adiciona(produto) {
    console.log(produto);
}
function adiciona(produto, categoria) {
    console.log(produto, categoria);
}

adiciona(1);
adiciona(1, 2);` não funcionou, ao menos o artigo deu a entender que funciona :/ (testado no Chrome)

Comment: Opa @GuilhermeNascimento eu fiquei curioso não saiba desse questão em Javascript que não é o meu forte, mas, rapaz eu não testei realmente a validade desse link, vou testa-lo e talvez alguma alma caridosa consiga nos nortear sobre isso ... ! Qualquer novidade eu te falo ... !!!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O link realmente tem alguns erros de codificação, mas pela logica que vi esta realmente ok, o problema é que estaria relacionado a métodos de uma função gerada, creio que não possa ser aplicado no `window`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert o teste que fiz foi assim `(function () {
        function adiciona(produto) {
            console.log("função 1", produto);
        }
        function adiciona(produto, categoria) {
            console.log("função 2", produto, categoria);
        }

        adiciona(1);
        adiciona(1, 2);
    })();`, e mesmo assim o unico resultado é a `"função 2"`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert esse do Users me parece o segundo exemplo, talvez seja falha na escrita do autor e ele queira dizer que aquilo não funcionava, quero dizer o texto me parece confuso

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [veja](https://jsfiddle.net/gyo0rruf/)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert isto eu cheguei a testar sim, o que estou falando realmente é de como o texto foi escrito, ele levou a uma má compreensão da situação na primeira parte, ao menos para mim pareceu isto *"Já em Javascript, definir uma função com o mesmo nome a sobrescreve:"* =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resposta sucinta:

Este é o comportamento "normal" em JavaScript. A linguagem tem avançado e hoje já é possível usar `const` para declarar constantes que não podem ser sobrescritas.

## Resposta alongada:

Desde o inicio que JavaScript permite sobrescrever nomes de variáveis e funções, e até mesmo atribuir valores a variáveis sem as declarar, "declarando-as" em escopo global, o que tem gerado bugs difíceis de detectar.

Nas versões modernas de JavaScript muito disto tem vindo a ser corrigido e para o teu caso a correção é usar `const`, atribuindo a uma variável uma função.

Assim em ECMAScript 2015 (a versão 6 de JavaScript) existe `const` que inicia uma variável que não pode ser mais sobre-escrita sem gerar erro de compilação.

#### As tuas perguntas:

> 1. Esse é realmente o comportamento esperado quando declaramos 2
>      métodos com o mesmo nome e parâmetros no js, ele irá sempre
>      sobrescrever e vai prevalecer o último declarado?

Sim. A não ser que uses `const` (que vai gerar um erro caso os nomes sejam iguais). Esse é o comportamento normal, igual ao CSS, o ultimo a ser declarado pervalece.

> 2. Existe alguma explicação para esse comportamento, se sim qual é essa
>      explicação?

É assim que a linguagem foi construída, meio flexível... Mas está a ser reforçada/corrigida nas novas versões.

> 3. Existe alguma forma de fazer que gere algum erro ou algo do tipo
>      caso alguém cometa esse equivoco e declare 2 métodos com o mesmo
>      nome e parâmetros?

Sim, usando `const` o problema fica corrigido. Ou seja, dá erro caso uma variável seja sobre-escrita. Nesse caso podes usar:

```
const teste = function(){
    console.log('teste 1');
}
```

e se fizeres seguidamente `const teste = outra coisa...` o compilador dá erro e não corre.

> 4. Caso a 3 tenha alguma maneira de fazer, o que fazer caso as funções
>      estejam em arquivos js diferentes?

Nesse caso tens de encapsular as coisas. Ou usas módulos CJS, AMD ou ES6. Ainda não há uma especificação universal por parte da linguagem, mas há propostas que estão em análise nesse sentido. Se usares o compilador da Babel já podes usar esses modulos.

**Assim há duas respostas:**

Com módulos compilados podes declarar tudo no escopo "global" pois o módulo não partilha esse escopo com outros ficheiros. Todas as variáveis ficam encapsuladas e a unica coisa que podes exportar para fora do módulo é via a palavra reservada `exports`. Um exemplo:

```
function teste(){
    console.log(1);
}

module.exports = teste;
```

dessa maneira `teste` não é visivel a outros ficheiros.

Usando JavaScript nativo, onde todos os ficheiros partilham o espaço global:

Aqui tens de encapsular tu próprio as coisas. O conceito é idêntico mas tens de usar [IIFEs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129) para esconder as variáveis umas das outras.

Por exemplo:

```js
// ficheiro A
(function(global) {
  function teste() {
    console.log('teste A');
  }

  global.testeA = teste;

})(this);

// ficheiro B
(function(global) {
  function teste(nr) {
    var res = nr * nr;
    console.log('teste B', res);
  }
  global.testeB = teste;

})(this);

testeA();
testeB(17);
```

Answer (score 27):

Creio que você tecnicamente já respondeu "ele sobrescreve", mas outro também é necessário entender uma característica de `function ... ()`, então vou explicar um comportamento para duas maneira de declarar uma função e então em seguida explico isto.

Em JavaScript você pode fazer:

```
function x() {
}

x();
```

E setando na variável:

```
x = function() {
}
x();
```

Em ambos casos irá funcionar, no entanto `function x()` é diferente de `x = function()`, pois se fizer isto:

Vai funcionar:

```
x();

function x() {
}
```

Não vai funcionar, irá acusar como `undefined`:

```
x();

x = function() {
}
```

Agora o motivo, o JavaScript, assim como muitas linguagens, fazem um "pré processamento" de algumas coisas declaradas, ou seja quando faz isto:

```
x();

function x() {
}
```

Ele irá ocorrer antes do tempo de execução e deixará todas funções que foram declaradas assim `function ...()` prontas para uso antes da execução de fato, ou seja quando faz isto:

```js
function teste() {
  console.log("teste1");
}

teste();

function teste() {
  console.log("teste2");
}

teste();
```

Veja que aparece `teste2` duas vezes.

### Porque isto ocorre

O "motor EcmaScript" (JavaScript) do navegador irá processar a sua maneira (é provável que apesar de internamente funcionarem parecidos ainda sim possam trabalhar de maneira diferentes para atingir o mesmo resultado) e provavelmente ele irá só considerar a função mais nova, ou seja no tempo de execução o primeiro `teste()` provavelmente não existe mais.

**Mesmo em tempo de execução** provavelmente o JavaScript **é pré-processado**, se olhar no exemplo a seguir, mesmo chamando `x()` antes ao invés de exibir `oi`, irá inicialmente exibir `11`:

```js
function x() {
   console.log("oi");
}

var a = 10;

window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
         x();

         function x() {
             console.log(++a);
         }
     };
};
```

```html
<button id="test">Teste</button>
```

---

> **Nota:** O link citado pelo Virgilo aparentemente dá a entender que funções com diferentes parâmetros são suportados, mas conforme testes não é possivel, veja:

```js
function adiciona(a) {
    console.log("função 1 => ", a);
}
function adiciona(b, c) {
    console.log("função 2 => ", b, c);
}

adiciona(1);
adiciona(1, 2);
```

O exemplo retorna:

```
função 2 =>  1 undefined
função 2 =>  1 2
```

---

### Alternativa

Conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187697/1518921), um exemplo simples de checar o que deseja chamar seria:

```js
function foo(a, b, c)
{
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    console.log("foo 1");
  } else if (arguments.length == 3) {
    console.log("foo 2");
  }
}

foo(1, 2);
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

E existem mais alternativas ainda mais complexas para atingir o "efeito" desejado, mas realmente eu creio que isto seja algo totalmente desnecessário, provavelmente no incio vindo de linguagens como [java](/questions/tagged/java) você sinta algum desconforto, mas não é algo que realmente faça tanta falta assim.

Comment: no link ele diz que tem que ser implementado um código adicional para que funcione o `overload`, não sei em que aspecto isso e bom ou ruim, mas, eu fiz o teste do jeito que está no [link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/possibilitando-o-overload-de-metodos-em-javascript/) e funcionou, observe: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/p50bonq3/), agora realmente como foi descrito na pergunta ele sobrescreve ficando válido somente 1.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic otimos exemplos, só não coloquei algo assim porque realmente eu acho que funcionalidades como esta são bem dispensáveis. Mas o seu comentário está ótimo para futuros visitantes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, também é bom adiantar que ``(function(){...})();`` é usado para criar um escopo próprio e assim impedir que uma função sobrescreva outra, especialmente se estiverem em arquivos diferentes. A desvantagem é que você precisa passar quaisquer funções e variáveis globais que você queira dentro do escopo no início e no final dessa chamada: ``(function(minha_biblioteca){...})(minha_biblioteca);``

Comment: E ainda protege o escopo?

Comment: @Daniel acho que entendi, você está se referindo as variáveis mesmo e não aos objetos, desculpe a confusão, sim o IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) tem realmente este objetivo, na verdade os exemplos nem deveriam conter isto, é que por padrão eu sempre uso IIFE em meus script, foi força do habito. Tem alguns links do proprio site, depois adicionado a resposta. Só note que passar por argumento é apenas uma das maneiras de proteger o escopo. Obrigado o/

Answer (score 8):

Complementando as respostas, caso você não queira que a sua função seja sobrescrita, e mantenha seus valores, você pode criá-las através da `const`

```js
const teste = function () {
    console.log("Teste1")
}

teste()

var teste = function teste() {
    console.log("Teste2")
}

teste()
```

TypeError: const 'teste' has already been declared

Execution Time-70ms

```js
var teste = function() {
    console.log("Teste1")
}

teste()

var teste = function() {
    console.log("Teste2")
}

teste()
```

Teste1

Teste2

Execution Time-48ms

Comment: Achei uma excelente sugestão Oracy, exatamente como o autor da pergunta pediu, parabéns +1