# Como carregar js estilo o google analytcs

Tags: javascript, google, async

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde teria que adicionar somente uma tag no site do cliente e ja carregar o js com todas as funções. segue o exemplo do google analytcs:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','IDDDDD');
```

alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se organizares esse código minificado ficaria assim:

```
(function(w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'IDDDDD');
```

Esse código pode ser analizado em 3 partes:

- uma [closure](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1862/129), para criar um escopo dentro dessa [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129) e poder ter variáveis de nomes bem mais curtos.
- preenchimento de uma array em `window.dataLayer`
- inserir o script no DOM, antes da primeira tag script, assíncrono

Julgo que a terceira parte é a que te interessa. Juntando a primeira e a segunda, poderias ter algo assim:

```
(function(d, s) {
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s);
    j.async = true;
    j.src = 'https://o.teu.url.aqui';
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(document, 'script');
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado. me ajudou bastante...