# O que significa o sinal de "+" na frente da função no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pesquisando um pouco sobre validação de formulários no [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), encontrei o [bootstrap-validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator), no qual exatamente no arquivo [validator.js](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/blob/master/js/validator.js), como podem ver, possui a notação *`+funcion`*. Observem o código abaixo:

```
+function($) { 
     /* conteúdo */
}(jQuery);
```

O que significa o sinal "+" na frente da função no JavaScript?

Comment: Relacionada no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13341698/1452488

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`+` é um atalho, um caracter em vêz de dois `()`, que seria a maneira mais fácil de lêr para invocar uma função `(...a declaração da função..)()`.

O `+` vai forçar a parte seguinte ao operador a ser interpretada como uma expressão, ou seja uma declaração de função e vai fazer com que a função corra uma vez que ela é seguida de `()`.

```js
+function(m) {
  console.log('Olá ' + m + '!');
}('mundo')
```

Esse tipo de funções chamam-se [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129), e esse tipo de sintaxe encurtada pode ser feito com o conversor/operador `+`, ou negação `!` ou bitwise `~`. A ideia é poupar caracteres.

```js
!function() {console.log('Usando !');}();

~function() {console.log('Usando ~');}();

-function() {console.log('Usando -');}();

(function() {console.log('Usando ()');})();
```

Pessoalmente acho que `(function...)()` , ou a variante `(function(){}())`, é mais claro, e por isso a maneira correta. Portanto não usando outros operadores que têm como função outra coisa, mas que como efeito colateral fazem o browser a interpretar a código e poupam 1 caractere.

Comment: Resposta sensacional +1

Comment: Então o `!`, `~`, `-` tem mesmo objetivo do `+` ?

Comment: @acklay neste contexto sim, mas a sua semântica é diferente, ou seja fazem coisas diferentes se forem usadas para o propósito para o qual foram criadas. Mas neste contexto todas têm o mesmo efeito colateral, por isso fazem o mesmo.

Comment: @Sergio, quando !, ~, - pode ter um efeito diferente?

Comment: @WictorChaves para o efeito de chamar uma função não, é igual. Mas cada um tem uma função específica no contexto para que foi criado. `!` é para negação, `~` é inversor de bitwise, etc.