# Qual o comportamento de 2 funções anônimas em um objeto?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, função-anônima

Explico:

```
StarGate = {};
StarGate.c = {}; 
StarGate.c.m = function(t, e){
  return "teste1";
},function(g){
  console.log('teste2');
}(StarGate.c.m.prototype);
```

Tenho dúvidas pois, qual seria o comportamento da segunda função? Ela sobrepõe a primeira função no objeto? Ela é executada assim que criada, desse modo ela tem acesso as propriedades e métodos do objeto em questão?

O trecho do código real que tenho é esse(Não tinha colocado anteriormente pois achei que poderia ficar grande na pergunta):

```
StarGate.c.m = function(t, e, a) {
    var o = arguments.length;
    2 === o && (a = 1), 2 === o || 3 === o ? (this.phi = t, this.theta = e, this.rad = a) : (o = t.x * t.x + t.y * t.y, 
    this.rad = Math.sqrt(o + t.z * t.z), this.phi = 0 === t.x && 0 === t.y ? 0 : Math.atan2(t.y, t.x), 
    this.phi < 0 && (this.phi += StarGate.b.p), o = Math.sqrt(o), this.theta = 0 === t.z && 0 === o ? 0 : Math.atan2(t.z, o));
}, function(g) {
    g.G = function() {
        var t = Math.cos(this.theta);
        e = this.rad;
        return new StarGate.c.k(e * g * Math.cos(this.phi), e * g * Math.sin(this.phi), e * Math.sin(this.theta));
    };

    g.K = function() {
        return new StarGate.c.m(this.rad, this.phi, this.theta);
    };
}(StarGate.c.m.prototype);
```

Agradecido

Answer (score 3):

Des-recomendo vivamente escrever código dessa maneira. Porque o *operador virgula* gera código difícil de ler, e porque passar protótipos como argumentos de funções vai gerar complexidade e consequentemente comportamentos inesperados.

O *operador virgula* neste caso executa o primeiro comando que vai atribuir a `.c.m` o valor de uma função; e como isso retorna algo com valor Booleano *true*, o que faz que ele execute o outro comando dessa sequência de dois comandos separados por virgula.

Tendo dito isso o que se passa aí, na prática é:

```
StarGate = {};
StarGate.c = {}; 
StarGate.c.m = function(t, e){
  return "teste1";
};
(function(g){
  console.log('teste2');
})(StarGate.c.m.prototype);
```

Ou seja, tudo "normal" até à [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210130/o-que-significa-o-sinal-de-na-frente-da-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-javascript/210144#210144). Essa função tem na variável `g` uma referência da função que retorna `teste1` em [`.contructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) e podes usá-la para invocar essa função:

```js
StarGate = {};
StarGate.c = {};
StarGate.c.m = function(t, e) {
    return "teste1";
  },
  function(g) {
    console.log('teste2', String(g.constructor()));

    console.log('A descrição da função:', String(g.constructor));

    console.log('O retorno de invocar a função: ', g.constructor());
  }(StarGate.c.m.prototype);
```

Em relação ao que é possível aceder e o o contexto de execução, deixo um exemplo. Mas uma função atribuída a uma propriedade de objeto nunca pode aceder aos níveis superiores se não for chamada explicitamente com outro contexto.

```js
StarGate = {};
StarGate.c = {};
StarGate.c.m = function(t, e) {
  console.log(this);
};

(function(g) {
console.log(g);
  g.constructor(); // protótipo
  g.constructor.call(StarGate); // o objeto base
  StarGate.c.m(); // o objeto aninhado onde m é declarado
})(StarGate.c.m.prototype);

// Abre isto na consola do browser
```

Comment: Mas, os métodos e tributos do objeto, são acessíveis pela segunda função anônima? O que eu pus na pergunta é somente uma parte do código que tenho, pois acredito que ficaria grande para por aqui.

Comment: Você não recomenda essa forma, qual seria uma forma mais adequada desse código?

Comment: @GilsonJosé juntei 3 exemplos de maneiras de chamar a função com contextos de execução diferentes. Em relação a outra maneira de fazer depende da aplicação. Como está é complexo e difícil de ler. Separando em IIFE como juntei na resposta já seria melhor.

Comment: Eu atualizei o corpo da pergunta para entender melhor. A segunda função anônima, pelo que entendi está acessando os atributos do objeto Stargate.c certo?

Comment: @GilsonJosé juntares esse código todo explode a pergunta :) Analizar esse código e dar-te uma resposta segura carece de mais tempo do que aquele que eu tenho disponível e duvido que a pergunta seja interessante para outras pessoas, pois fica demasiado específica. A segunda função anónima pode aceder a `Stargate.c ` pois ele foi declarado antes de a função executar. Mas para isso tens de ter `Stargate.c ` dentro da função, indo pelo `this` não chegas lá o JavaScript não permite.