# JavaScript mudou suas regras sobre o que é falso ou verdadeiro?

Tags: javascript, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo, booleano

Me ocorreu na parte sobre booleanos, o seguinte problema.

Tenho esta variável:

```js
var name = "10kg" / 10;

if (name) {
  console.log(name);
} else {
  console.log("Not exist");
}
```

A mesma deveria me retornar: `Not Exist`, no console. Porém aparece como `NaN` (Not a Number).

Acabei de ler a documentação no Firefox e diz que se for `0`, `-0`, `null`, `NaN`, `underfined`, essa tem que me retornar `false`, ou seja como determinei `Not Exist`, porém nesse caso eles retornarão os resultados na condição do `else`.

Eu escrevi o código errado? A regra mudou? Ou não interpretei corretamente a documentação?

Pois na aula foi feito dessa forma e apareceu no console o resultado desejado.

Comment: O curioso é que se testar esse código no NodeJs esse código retorna `Not exist` e se o testar no Deno ele não compila com o erro `error: TS2362 [ERROR]: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
let name = "10kg" / 10;` com o `"10kg"` desatacado.

Comment: Isso é realmente com o colega explicou, são armadilhas, e os novatos (eu aqui tbm me incluo), caem nisso e nem fazem ideia do ocorrido. Muito estranho.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regras de linguagens de programação não podem mudar, o mundo inteiro depende delas estáveis, quebraria tudo o que as pessoas fizeram.

Bem, na verdade até mudam quando havia um erro grave na linguagem, ou estamos falando de PHP que não se importa em quebrar um monte de coisa e deixar todo mundo na mão. Mas nem sei se isso é ruim porque eles melhoram vários erros que a linguagem tinha. Claro, tem um lado bem ruim.

JavaScript é uma linguagem cheia de regras ruins. Quase todos problemas da linguagem está relacionada com as regras mal definidas.

## Tipagem dinâmica contra o DOM

No caso específico há erros por causa da tipagem fraca que é algo que uma linguagem não deveria ter, isso causa vários problemas, e há erro por causa da implementação mal feita do DOM no navegador.

Vamos mudar o código para ver melhor o que está acontecendo:

```js
var name = "10kg" / 10;
console.log(typeof name);
if (name) console.log(name);
else console.log("Not exist");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/WrongCoersion.js).

Note que a variável `name` é do tipo `string`. Então como um número é do tipo `string`? Ao contrário do padrão que aprendemos que JS tem tipagem dinâmica, variáveis de objeto do DOM não são de tipagem dinâmica e se você colocar um valor de um tipo diferente do que espera aí sim a linguagem implicitamente converte o valor para o tipo da variável.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/WrongCoersion2.js).

## Tipagem fraca

Então tem outro erro de tipagem fraca. Quando um texto pode ser completamente convertido para número ele é, e isso não deveria acontecer. Mas quando tem uma parte que é texto, a conversão não ocorre, e aí em vez de gerar um valor válido gera um NaN.

Depois vem outro erro da tipagem fraca. Quando usa um valor em um lugar que espera um booleano ele usa a regra de conversão automática para obter o valor esperado, e uma *string* com um texto qualquer é verdadeiro. A [regra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) é bem clara quanto a isso, só uma *string* vazia é falsa (que é outra regra esquisita). Aí tem um texto, não é vazio. Isso deveria ser proibido em qualquer linguagem decente, mas não é em JS.

Três conversões automáticas que não deveriam ter sido feitas causaram a confusão. E em geral as pessoas não entendem ou não sabem delas. Justamente por não ser intuitivo não deveria ser permitido.

O que você tem que fazer?

- Nunca use um valor que não seja especificamente do tipo que deseja. Não faça uma divisão com uma *string* e não use um valor que não seja um booleano onde se espera um valor assim, como o `if` por exemplo. Se você sempre lembrar disso JS será uma experiência muito melhor para você.
- Nunca use nome de variáveis do DOM, a não ser que ela seja tratada como local. Já explico

Feito assim nem precisa do `if` porque ele trata de um erro de programação, e erros de programação devem ser consertados e não verificados em execução, não pode ser tratado como algo válido, ainda que a linguagem permita.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Ainda que este caso nem funcionou com o resultado esperado.

Funciona perfeitamente (mas ainda não é certo):

```js
var name = 10 / 10;
if (name) console.log(name);
else console.log("Not exist");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/WrongCoersion3.js).

Melhor ainda para criar um booleano do jeito certo:

```js
var name = 10 / 10;
if (name != 0) console.log(name);
else console.log("Not exist");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/WrongCoersion4.js).

## Nome de variável inadequado

Uma variável numérica chamada `name` gera confusão (geraria mesmo que fosse `nome` porque nomes não são números). E aí vemos o problema do JavaScript (no navegador). Vamos mudar o nome:

```js
var x = "10kg" / 10;
console.log(typeof x);
if (x) console.log(x);
else console.log("Not exist");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/WrongCoersion5.js).

Note que mudando o nome da variável o comportamento é outro. A conversão não é feita e acontece o que esperava. Na verdade até tem uma conversão, mas ela é feita depois.

`name` na verdade não é uma variável local, ela é a variável do DOM cujo nome completo é `window.name` e não pode ter seu tipo trocado.

Dá para usar o `name` se garantir que está usando uma variável local:

```js
let name = "10kg" / 10;
console.log(typeof name);
if (name) console.log(name);
else console.log("Not exist");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/WrongCoersion6.js).

Por isso no Node/Deno pode acontecer diferente (veja comentário acima), o que é outra maluquice do ecossistema inteiro. Mas nada estranho porque toda tecnologia web foi mal pensada.

## Conclusão

E esse é mais um motivo que eu posso afirmar que tipagem dinâmica é errada na maioria dos cenários, não é só tipagem fraca que é ruim em todos. Até mesmo em *scripts* que eu achava certo, está errado porque eles costumam ser usados embarcados em outras aplicações que não possuem tipagem dinâmica e cria uma impedância, e aí acontece tudo isso.

JavaScript não deveria permitir conversões automáticas que causam confusão. Mesmo no caso do DOM que não pode ter tipagem dinâmica, a solução deveria ser dar um erro de execução quando tenta mudar o tipo da variável e não fazer uma conversão sem sentido. Viola o estilo de tipagem, mas não gera um resultado falso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, achei muito boa sua explicação vou anotar isso, para não esquecer. Vlu mesmo.

Answer (score 9):

Isso não é nenhum problema na sua lógica. Isso é uma armadilha do JavaScript.

No JavaScript do seu navegador, quando você declara uma variável no escopo global, ela se torna uma propriedade do objeto `window`.

Assim como outros elementos do html como `head`, `body`, `div`, etc, o objeto `window` também possui uma propriedade chamada `name`. Essa propriedade `name` porém possui um setter, e esse setter irá transformar qualquer valor que você atribuir para ele numa string, pois por padronização, a propriedade `name` de um elemento só pode armazenar strings.

Como você utilizou uma variável chamada `name` no seu escopo global, você na verdade está armazenando o valor de `NaN` na propriedade `name` de `window`, o que significa que `NaN` está sendo convertida numa string `'NaN'`, e como você deve saber, um string não vazia é tratada como uma condição verdadeira.

Faça o teste.

Utilizando `name`:

```js
var name = "10kg" / 10;

if (typeof name === 'string') {
  console.log('name é uma string')
}

if (name) {
  console.log('e como name é uma string não vazia, ela é verdadeira')
}
```

Utilizando qualquer outro nome:

```js
var result = "10kg" / 10;

if (typeof result === 'string') {
  console.log('name é uma string')
} else {
  console.log('result NÃO é uma string')
}

if (result) {
  console.log('e como result é uma string não vazia, ela é verdadeira')
} else {
  console.log('result é de fato NaN, e portanto, é uma condição falsa')
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado támbem, informação muito precisa, não sabia desses detalhes, vou anotar támbem para não esquecer e utilizar em meu código.

Answer (score 8):

Isso **não** é uma armadilha do JavaScript, na verdade é uma **"armadilha do JavaScript em navegadores"** e não tem haver com tipagem.

Quando você usa `name` no escopo principal ele vai entender que se refere ao `window.name`, que por padrão já vem setado como uma string vazia, o valor de `"10kg" / 10` será `NaN`, como a propriedade `Window.name` só aceita string ele vai fazer um "cast" automático para string, fazendo o valor em `"NaN"`, então por isso que ocorre do `name.length` funcionar, se por acaso usasse qualquer outro nome de variável que não exista no escopo principal em `window.{...}` vai ocorrer um erro, já que não vai converter para `string`:

```js
var foobar = "10kg" / 10;

console.log("variável foobar:", foobar);
console.log("typeof foobar:", typeof foobar);

var name = "10kg" / 10;

console.log("variável name:", name);
console.log("typeof name:", typeof name);
```

Veja que a variável `foobar` retornou `Number` (mesmo que NaN signifique não ser um numero, ainda sim é parte dessa interface e por isso o `typeof` retorna assim).

Qualquer outra propriedade "*writable*", por exemplo, se fizer `var location = "10kg" / 10;` no escopo principal você irá fazer a página redirecionar para um endereço como `http://localhost/NaN`:

[image: Resultado no navegador]

Ou seja, as propriedades do objeto `Window` podem ter variados comportamentos.

Note que uma situação semelhante **em navegadores** ocorre com IDs de elementos em páginas HTML:

- [Porque usar getElementById se o id está no window?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123098/3635)

Elementos com `id="..."` ficam disponíveis como propriedades do `window`.

### Em Node.js

Em [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) o código:

```
var name = "10kg" / 10;

console.log("variável name:", name);
console.log("typeof name:", typeof name);
```

o resultado será:

```
C:\Users\user>node index.js
variável name: NaN
typeof name: number
```

Ou seja, **não** é mesmo um problema com JavaScript e sim com certas decisões que implementações iniciais do JavaScript (NetScape/Mozilla), JScript (Internet Explorer), entre outros (época das primeiras guerra dos navegadores), essas decisões provavelmente se mantém por questões de retrocompatibilidade.

### Usando `let` (ou `const`)

Como já explicado em [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando "let" e "var"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/3635), o comportamento do `let` é diferente de `var`, observe como **não** ocorre o problema:

```js
let name = "10kg" / 10;

console.log("variável name:", name);
console.log("typeof name:", typeof name);
```

O mesmo irá ocorrer com `const`, não irão acessar a propriedades de `window`.

No entanto note que certas propriedades podem ser **não configuráveis** (non-configurable), mesmo com `let` não vai resolver, ocasionando o erro:

> SyntaxError: redeclaration of non-configurable global property location

```js
let location = "10kg" / 10;

console.log("variável location:", location);
console.log("typeof location:", typeof location);
```

Portanto uma melhor saída para evitar certos acidentes é isolar o escopo, como por exemplo com IIFE ou usar `let` em um `block` (`{...}`) (veja os exemplos a seguir).

### Usando IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Antes de termos o `let` já existia uma "técnica" para evitar o escopo principal, que também ajuda evitar que outros scripts não relacionados conflitem no escopo principal, ficando assim:

```js
(function () {
    var name = "10kg" / 10;
    var location = "10kg" / 10;

    console.log("variável name:", name);
    console.log("typeof name:", typeof name);

    console.log("variável location:", location);
    console.log("typeof location:", typeof location);
})();
```

Claro que isso não é a mesma coisa que o `let`, só estou citando como um meio de isolar o escopo, nessas respostas algumas falam mais sobre isso:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Respostas do site sobre o assunto:

- [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/3635)
- [Sobre (function(){ ... }()) e callThis()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/3635)
- [O que significa o sinal de "+" na frente da função no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210130/3635) (esse é só uma "curiosidade")

### Usando `block` e `let`

Se pretende rodar os scripts somente em navegadores modernos sem se preocupar com retrocompatibilidade, então pode combinar [`block` (`{...}`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#Block_scoping_rules_with_var_or_function_declaration_in_non-strict_mode) com `let`, poderá setar variáveis sem afetar o escopo global

```js
{
    let name = "10kg" / 10;
    let location = "10kg" / 10;

    console.log("variável name:", name);
    console.log("typeof name:", typeof name);

    console.log("variável location:", location);
    console.log("typeof location:", typeof location);
}
```

Este exemplo irá funcionar no Internet Explorer 11, mas não irá funcionar em anteriores, como IE8, IE9 e IE10.