# Diferença entre duas funções que executam apenas uma vez em javascript

Tags: javascript

Procurei um script que fizesse realizar uma função apenas uma vez e achei a função abaixo

```js
var something = (function() {
    var executed = false;
    return function () {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            alert("olá");
        }
    };
})();
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="something()">Executar</a>
```

Pois bem, funciona perfeitamente!

Porém não entendi o porque de tanto código visto que resumi ela dessa forma e também funciona perfeitamente

```js
    var executada = false;
    function chama() {
        if (!executada) {
            executada = true;
            alert("olá");
        }
    };
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="chama()">Executar</a>
```

Alguma razão especifica no primeiro código?

Comment: Tem alguém me perseguindo dando downvoto em tudo que é de minha autoria!! lamentável isso. Que há de errado na minha pergunta?  Esse tipo de conduta não adiciona nada de útil ao proposito do site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A razão dessas [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129), em particular no teu exemplo, é criar um bloco de escopo próprio, para ter variáveis "internas".

Repara que a variável `executada` no segundo exemplo fica global, podendo ser mudada sem querer noutras partes do código. Enquanto que no primeiro exemplo ela é local e não pode ser modificada de fora dessa [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129).

Nesse primeiro exemplo `executed` fica como um tipo de memória da função criada em baixo com `return function () {`, e como não pode ser modificada de fora da [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129) isso é muito útil.

Para além do caso que referes no exemplo, podes ler mais exemplos aqui [(nesta resposta)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23788/129).

Comment: Nem vou esperar por outra resposta para decidir qual aceitar uma vez que a resposta foi dada pelo Rei do JavaScript :)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo :) Numa proxima vez podes sempre esperar por outra, há por aqui gente que explica melhor que eu. Mas fico contente de a resposta ter respondido á tua dúvida.

Comment: Posso dizer que no primeiro `executed` está no escopo lexical e no segundo escopo global?

Comment: @Marconi Sim, podes. _"Lexical scoping"_ é uma característica da linguagem, neste caso seria "escopo global" e "escopo léxico da função".