# Erro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Galera, 
sou novato em javascript e estou tentando fazer um exercicio que consiste em criar um botão que gera quadrados empilhados toda vez que é clicado. a questão é ja revisei esse codigo diversas vezes e não acho o erro. E tambem meu botão sempre é acionado automatimamente toda vez que a pagina carrega. Preciso entender o motivo disso acontecer

```js
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button#btn');
var boxApp = document.querySelector('div#app');
//console.log(btnElement);
//console.log(boxApp);

btnElement.onclick = criarQuadrados();

function criarQuadrados(){
    var quadrado = document.createElement('div');
    quadrado.style.width = '100px';
    quadrado.style.height = '100px';
    quadrado.style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
    boxApp.appendChild(quadrado);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Exercicio 01</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Clique em mim</button>
    <div id = "app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so isso resolveu o problema kkkk mas não entendi, criarQuadrados é uma função, eu não tinha que chamar ela usando os parenteses ?

Comment: Para entender sobre a função, veja essa pergunta: [Sobre (function(){ … }()) e callThis()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23785) leia a resposta dada pelo *Sergio*. No caso eu mosquei aqui e não é necessário alterar os seletores: `('button#btn')` e `('div#app')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está em ' btnElement.onclick = criarQuadrados() ', deste modo você está indicando que a função já deve ser imediatamente executada, quando na verdade ela só deve ser executada quando o botão for clicado. O código a seguir deverá funcionar para você.

```js
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button#btn');
var boxApp = document.querySelector('div#app');

btnElement.onclick = function criarQuadrados(){
    var quadrado = document.createElement('div');
    quadrado.style.width = '100px';
    quadrado.style.height = '100px';
    quadrado.style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
    boxApp.appendChild(quadrado);
}
```

Comment: Realmente resolveu meu problema, mas agora tenho outra duvida, eu fiz dessa forma "btnElement.onclick = criarQuadrados;" e funcionou tambem, porem achei meio estranho ele reconhecer uma função sendo que não coloquei os parenteses pra indicar que é uma função.

Comment: Em javascript quase tudo é um objeto, ao passar apenas o nome da função, você estará passando o conteúdo daquele objeto, já você passar o nome da função com os parenteses, você estará indicando que a função tem que ser executada naquele momento em que o código está sendo interpretado. Não sei se ficou claro, mas é isso.