# Fazer o código rodar depois das primeiras linhas

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, pessoal! Estou tentando resolver um pequeno bugzinho aqui de um scritp que fiz para um site, sou iniciante ainda e não estou conseguindo resolver.

O que acontece, é: Preciso que o código rode somente depois dessa linha pq não ta dando tempo dos elementos existirem pra ele rodar

```
$( "#filtro-belem" ).load( "http://recursos.belempneusb2b.ecommercestore.com.br/c/filtro.html" );
```

```
$( "#filtro-belem" ).load( "http://recursos.belempneusb2b.ecommercestore.com.br/c/filtro.html" );

(function() {
const category = document.getElementById("category")
const width = document.getElementById("width")
const profile = document.getElementById("profile")
const wheel = document.getElementById("wheel")

const nextTypes = {
  category: width,
  width: profile,
  profile: wheel
}

function handleFilterType(type) {
    return () => {
        const { id, value } = type
        const currentOption = type.querySelector(`option[value='${value}']`).innerText

        const nextType = nextTypes[id]
        const options = nextType.querySelectorAll("option")

        options.forEach((option) => {
          if (!option.dataset || !option.dataset.relation) return null
          const acceptedTypes = option.dataset.relation.split("-")

          option.hidden = !acceptedTypes.includes(currentOption)
        })
    }
}

category.addEventListener("change", handleFilterType(category))
width.addEventListener("change", handleFilterType(width))
profile.addEventListener("change", handleFilterType(profile))
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse método [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) aceita uma função como segundo ou terceiro argumento que vai usar como [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#27182) quando o `.load` tiver corrido.

Assim, em vez de usar essa [IIFE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/129) podes colocar esse código dentro dessa callback:

```js
$("#filtro-belem").load("http://recursos.belempneusb2b.ecommercestore.com.br/c/filtro.html", function() {
  const category = document.getElementById("category")
  const width = document.getElementById("width")
  const profile = document.getElementById("profile")
  const wheel = document.getElementById("wheel")

  const nextTypes = {
    category: width,
    width: profile,
    profile: wheel
  }

  function handleFilterType(type) {
    return () => {
      const {
        id,
        value
      } = type
      const currentOption = type.querySelector(`option[value='${value}']`).innerText

      const nextType = nextTypes[id]
      const options = nextType.querySelectorAll("option")

      options.forEach((option) => {
        if (!option.dataset || !option.dataset.relation) return null
        const acceptedTypes = option.dataset.relation.split("-")

        option.hidden = !acceptedTypes.includes(currentOption)
      })
    }
  }

  category.addEventListener("change", handleFilterType(category))
  width.addEventListener("change", handleFilterType(width))
  profile.addEventListener("change", handleFilterType(profile))
});
```

Comment: Wow, muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!
Se não for pedir muito, eu teria mais uma questão. Tenho dois códigos desse numa mesma página. Porém o JS só está aplicando em um deles. Teria alguma ideia de como posso fazer?

Comment: @KaioAlmeida estão os dois apontados a `#filtro-belem`? ou o outro tem outro selector?

Comment: Os dois estão com apontamento a #filtro-belem. 

E tenho esse mesmo html em outras páginas. Estou tentando resolver essa parte tentando puxar com JS ou algo do tipo pra não ter que copiar o mesmo código para as outras páginas, mas um passo de cada vez

Comment: @KaioAlmeida se tens os dois a apontar para `#filtro-belem` eles vão sobreescrever-se um ao outro... IDs têm de ser únicos em HTML. Coloca outro ID em vez de `#filtro-belem`...

Comment: Nossa, não. Eu entendi errado mesmo.. Na realidade, o que ta sendo puxado duas vezes é o arquivo filtro.html. O JS ta carregando várias vezes a página. Desculpe pelo meu erro