# Integridade da Global window no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando com games onlines em navegadores e preciso tonar o cliente um ambiente mais seguro...

Inicialmente penso na raiz que é a Global `window`, como manter sua integridade diante seus valore já definidos pelo navegador mas com possibilidade de mudar, exemplo:

by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log

```js
let oldLog = console.log;

    console.log = function (message) {

            // DO MESSAGE HERE.

            // CODIGO CAPITURA
            oldLog('CAPITURA')

            oldLog.apply(console, arguments);

    };

    console.log('teste')
```

Sei que não posso congelar todas as propriedades porem pretendo congelar as funções e valores nativos se possivel, valores imutáveis, assim utilizo funções já existentes e ganho performance diminuindo custo de memoria...

comunicarei com o servidor enviado a pilha de dados para retorno das chaves únicas de integridade dos valores ou outra forma que ainda não sei... existe outros fatores de segurança porem como a Global `window` e bem delicado e grande, tenho um longo caminho...

Gostaria de atualizar algumas informações, achei algo muito interessante de uns dos engenheiros do Google, praticas que realmente deixam o código privado e seguro alem de ser eficiente na limpeza de memoria, aplicadas com IIFEs:

https://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/

Comment: Até dá pra fazer umas gambiarras, mas não vou ficar sugerindo tal coisa que vejo como um absurdo e um pensamento desnecessário, porque se fosse pra fazer e fosse eficiente ou mesmo se quer útil, todos o fariam, não tem muito o que se preocupar com isto, **simplesmente não trabalhe com escopo global**, isole as variáveis em um escopo, como o uso de IIFE (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), e controle tudo de lá e pronto, se tiver que liberar algo no global vai ser em ultimo caso.

Comment: Ótimo, já pratico está técnica mas não tinha detalhes delas, obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento!

Comment: Não vou votar para fechar por que tem gente que procura por isso. Mas eu não entendo a finalidade de decorar chamadas nativas isso é interessante de forma fechada em API proprietária mas fazer isso em código nativo pode levar a comportamento não esperado e  bugs indetectáveis.

Comment: Então, explique mais pois talvez não temos a mesma visão que você, também posso lhe dizer, o motivo é que estou criando um mmorpg e meu principal objetivo a trazer ele para o navegador além ser ser multi-plataforma, mas preciso torna o ambiente mais seguro e dificultar que ele mude uma função e espione os dados alterando as funções nativas que utilizo. Os dados da checagem de integridade será carregado via `cors` e depois despejados no lixo.

Comment: Eu só gostaria de deixar uma opinião que vejo em muitos que tem mais pontos aqui no Stack! Só pelo motivo de pode negativar uma pergunta ou duvida, fazem sem tentar entender realmente o real motivo, como vc disse, "eu não vou fechar...", talvez vc possa ser muito bom no que faz mas talvez vc também pode estar deixando de ver as coisas por quer só quer negativar o que não entende, seja humilde!

Comment: Não entendi sua acusação. Eu não negativei sua pergunta a encontrei em fila de análise para fechamento já com três votos para fechar. Eu deixei a observação para quem a encontrasse não a fechasse pois mesmo eu achando um dispositivo inócuo e que causa problemas de difícil detecção durante o desenvolvimento, há uma procura e provavelmente um motivo. Você alegou o seu, mesmo que não faça sentido pois tem impacto zero em segurança se a pessoa estiver disposta a modificar o comportamento do script ela simplesmente faz manipulado o script antes de iniciar ou usa o Vimion.

Comment: Eu não lhe acusei, e sim disse o que vejo aqui. Voltando ao assunto, acho que você ainda não entendeu! Você pode modificar tranquilamente mas a checagem de integridade saberá!

Comment: Mais uma observação pois existe uma contradição, você diz que talvez gere bugs ou erros... mas na real quem estará tentando modificar o script no caso aqui a Global `window` e alguém que não deveria fazer, por qual motivo algum faria uma alteração em um script que esta funcionando? A resposta nos já sabemos!

Comment: Eu parto do principio que todo cliente irá sacanear o sistema em algum ponto. Eu não acho prudente montar dispositivos de segurança do lado cliente, ainda mais jogo onde jogadores usam browser customizado em busca de vantagem.  A não ser que seja um honey pot e toda verificação da informação recebida ocorra do lado servidor e o que o cliente modificar na sua máquina fique só na sua máquina..

Comment: Justamente @AugustoVasques, por isso quero dificultar o trabalho desse tipo de user, se ele editar algo o sistema indicara que ele não deve fazer e caso continue sera bloqueado, além disso envio os dados que ele tentou editar para estudo e melhoria da segurança de integridade.

Comment: Quando eu quero trapacear em algum jogo online eu crio duas instancias da fonte uma para verificação de integridade, e  outras checagens, e outra instância só para enviar HTTP modificado.Se o jogo não realizar um conferencia nos dados ao receber eu faço o que quiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas ideias que se costumam usar para o código ser mais seguro (a primeira refere-se ao teu exemplo, e propriedades de `window`) :

- regista como imutáveis as propriedades de window

No trabalho fizemos assim:

```
 const defineConstantProperty = function(key, value){
    Object.defineProperty(window, key, {
        value: value,
        writable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: false
    });
};

defineConstantProperty('propriedade', {% valor %});
```

e podes até testar isso no teu exemplo:

```js
const defineConstantProperty = function(key, value, obj) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj || window, key, {
    value: value,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false
  });
};

defineConstantProperty('console', console);
defineConstantProperty('log', console.log, console);

let oldLog = console.log;

console.log = function(message) {
  oldLog('CAPITURA')
  oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
};

console.log('teste')
```

- usar IIFEs para evitar variáveis no escopo global ([podes ler mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/129))
- usar `const` para evitar que variáveis sejam sobre escritas
- usar `let` e `const` pelas vantagens do seu escopo de bloco
- nunca confies no que vem do cliente, faz sempre verificação no servidor
- evita ter informação sensível em URLs ou em variáveis, usa sempre indicadores (ids que podes usar no servidor) em vez da informação sensível

Comment: Ótimo @Sergio, se possível, me envie mais dicas aqui para obter mais detalhes de segurança que você tem conhecimento, o que você acha, devo remover do window para evitar entradas e dificultar, como eu acho, devo remover EVAL que eu não uso, trabalho com módulos e trabalhadores serviceWorker para não travar o pois funciona em segundo plano.

Comment: @RobertCezar é dificil juntar tudo numa só resposta. O `eval` é regra básica sim, o `serviceWorker` tem a ver com a experiência para o utilizador não tanto com segunrança, evitar `window`  sim, referi IIFEs por isso.

Comment: Apenas uma duvida que surgiu, vamos ao exemplo, você disse ali "evitar `window` sim" isso que dizer que não devo criar var no scorpo global mas posso utilizar com confiança as funções da global como Worker ou Consolo assim que aplicar o método acima que me passou `defineConstantProperty`, ok? Se não, então tenho que criar meus métodos existentes na global porem no escorpo privado e protegido IIFE, tipo polymorphism?

Comment: @RobertCezar podes confiar se usares `defineConstantProperty`. Outro truque que se usava antes era criar uma iFrame e copiar os métodos de `window` dessa iframe uma vez que o browser cria sempre uma iFrame com os métodos nativos.

Comment: Certo, mas acho que não é necessário criar o iframe, pois eu confirmo se o valor realmente é igual ao nativo, me corrija se eu estiver errado, exemplo: o valor nativo de `window.requestAnimationFrame` é `function requestAnimationFrame() { [native code] }` seu eu tentar acessar, então penso em fazer uma checagem do tipo simples, `String(window.requestAnimationFrame) === 'function requestAnimationFrame() { [native code] }'` ... isso depois de usar `defineConstantProperty`

Comment: @RobertCezar soa bem